# How can I create a PyCUDA GPUArray from a gpu memory address?

Tags: python, memory-address, pytorch, pycuda

I'm working with PyTorch and want to do some arithmetic on Tensor data with the help of PyCUDA. I can get a memory address of a cuda tensor `t` via `t.data_ptr()`. Can I somehow use this address and my knowledge of the size and data type to initialize a `GPUArray`? I am hoping to avoid copying the data, but that would also be an alternative.

Comment: No, I don't believe you could do that without writing some under-the-hood PyCUDA code yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this is possible.
We need a pointer do the data, which needs some additional capabilities:

```
class Holder(PointerHolderBase):

    def __init__(self, tensor):
        super().__init__()
        self.tensor = tensor
        self.gpudata = tensor.data_ptr()

    def get_pointer(self):
        return self.tensor.data_ptr()

    def __int__(self):
        return self.__index__()

    # without an __index__ method, arithmetic calls to the GPUArray backed by this pointer fail
    # not sure why, this needs to return some integer, apparently
    def __index__(self):
        return self.gpudata
```

We can then use this class to instantiate `GPUArray`s. The code uses Reikna arrays which are a subclass but should work with `pycuda` arrays as well.

```
def tensor_to_gpuarray(tensor, context=pycuda.autoinit.context):
    '''Convert a :class:`torch.Tensor` to a :class:`pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray`. The underlying
    storage will be shared, so that modifications to the array will reflect in the tensor object.
    Parameters
    ----------
    tensor  :   torch.Tensor
    Returns
    -------
    pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray
    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If the ``tensor`` does not live on the gpu
    '''
    if not tensor.is_cuda:
        raise ValueError('Cannot convert CPU tensor to GPUArray (call `cuda()` on it)')
    else:
        thread = cuda.cuda_api().Thread(context)
    return reikna.cluda.cuda.Array(thread, tensor.shape, dtype=torch_dtype_to_numpy(tensor.dtype), base_data=Holder(tensor))
```

We can go back with this code. I have not found a way to do this without copying the data.

```
def gpuarray_to_tensor(gpuarray, context=pycuda.autoinit.context):
    '''Convert a :class:`pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray` to a :class:`torch.Tensor`. The underlying
    storage will NOT be shared, since a new copy must be allocated.
    Parameters
    ----------
    gpuarray  :   pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray
    Returns
    -------
    torch.Tensor
    '''
    shape = gpuarray.shape
    dtype = gpuarray.dtype
    out_dtype = numpy_dtype_to_torch(dtype)
    out = torch.zeros(shape, dtype=out_dtype).cuda()
    gpuarray_copy = tensor_to_gpuarray(out, context=context)
    byte_size = gpuarray.itemsize * gpuarray.size
    pycuda.driver.memcpy_dtod(gpuarray_copy.gpudata, gpuarray.gpudata, byte_size)
    return out
```

---

### Old answer

```
from pycuda.gpuarray import GPUArray


def torch_dtype_to_numpy(dtype):
    dtype_name = str(dtype)[6:]     # remove 'torch.'
    return getattr(np, dtype_name)


def tensor_to_gpuarray(tensor):
    if not tensor.is_cuda:
        raise ValueError('Cannot convert CPU tensor to GPUArray (call `cuda()` on it)')
    else:
        array = GPUArray(tensor.shape, dtype=torch_dtype_to_numpy(tensor.dtype),
                         gpudata=tensor.data_ptr())
        return array.copy()
```

Unfortunately, passing an int as the `gpudata` keyword (or a subtype of `pycuda.driver.PointerHolderBase` as was suggested in the pytorch forum) seems to work on the surface, but many operations fail with seemingly unrelated errors. Copying the array seems to transform it into a useable format though.
I think it is related to the fact that the `gpudata` member should be a `pycuda.driver.DeviceAllocation` object which cannot be instantiated from Python it seems.

Now how to go back from the raw data to a Tensor is another matter.

Comment: As I said, this won't work without some under-the-hood modifications of PyCUDA

Comment: It can be done with copying, just not directly, unfortunately.